# React dynamic keys when re-rendering

Tags: reactjs

I have an array of objects, I map through the array and return a component for each.

Now, I for various reasons, I cant use the ID or the index as a unique key, so I'm using the short id library, the issue is that every time anything changes and it rerenders the array all the components get new Id's and the It loses focus since the Id changed

```
 {properties.map(property => (
            <PropertyForm key={shortid.generate()}/>
 ))}
```

This is my code, every time a specific property changes it gets rerendered and therefore regenerating its key.

Anu hint would be appreciated, Thanks

Comment: They'll only get new IDs if you're completely regenerating everything. If you save the generated ID with the data this won't happen: don't generate the UUID during rendering.

Comment: @DaveNewton I added my code to the answer, don't really see how I can avoid the rerendering since the state changes so it automatically rerenders

Comment: You should either use some data from `properties` array as unique ID (it can be combined from several properties of array element) or same generated unique IDs with data as already recommended. What is the content of `properties` array?

Comment: @Fyodor There is nothing I can use from the `properties` array since all values can be empty and also, the user can add empty ones by clicking "add property" which adds an empty property to the state

Comment: It can be a good idea to add some unique ids to every property. If you'll store them in DB, unique IDs will be usefull. Even if you'll not put them in DB, unique IDs will help you t distinguish between individual properties, for example to do sorting, filtering or modification.

Comment: @Fyodor The back-end is sending me back unique Ids for the DB but I can't use it since I allow the user to add new ones to the state and only on save I send it to the DB

Answer (score 1):

Before rendering, you have to generate a unique id for each object to avoid it.
More precisely, when an individual object is added to the array, it must generate a unique id of that new Object.

If you do not change the size or order of the object after the initialization of the array, you can use the key parameter of the map function.

```
 {properties.map((property, key) => (
            <PropertyForm key={key}/>
 ))}
```

But it is unsafe when it is mutable and I encourage you to follow the way of the former.